# Batch file: replace string in text of a file

Tags: batch-file, replace

I need some help in replacing some text in file using bat file.

I have such a template where I need to change version:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("5.1.1000.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("5.1.1000.0")]
```

I have written the next script but cannot understand how to change this version inside text:

```
REM %%f is a file where I will search a string a change it
for /f "tokens=2" %%p in ('findstr /r "[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]" %%f') do (
    echo %%p
)
```

Output:

```
AssemblyVersion("5.1.1000.0")
AssemblyFileVersion("5.1.1000.0")
```

How can I change 5.1.1000.0 to 7.1.1000.0,for example? That all text other text remains the same, only version will be changed.

Comment: I have solutions that will work with an executable (`sed`) or with a VBScript.  The extra executable would be far preferred.

Answer (score 1):

This will change any string from `Version("nnnnnnnnnnn")` to `Version("7.1.1000.0")` where nnnnn is any string of characters.

```
@echo off
type "file.txt" | repl "(Version\()\q.*\q(\))" "$1\q7.1.1000.0\q$2" x >"newfile.txt"
```

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` (by dbenham) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

SET "oldversion=5.1.1000.0"
SET "newversion=7.1.1000.0"

(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q24144143.txt) DO (
 SET "string=%%a"
 SET "string=!string:%oldversion%=%newversion%!"
 ECHO(!string!
)
)>newfile.txt

FC q24144143.txt newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q24144143.txt` containing your data for my testing.
Produces newfile.txt

[Revision to extract olversion first]

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

SET "oldversion="
SET "newversion=7.1.1000.0"

FOR /f "tokens=2delims=()" %%a IN ('findstr /r "[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]" q24144143.txt') DO (
 SET "oldversion=%%~a"
)

IF NOT DEFINED oldversion ECHO could NOT FIND old version&GOTO :EOF 
ECHO(oldversion=%oldversion%

(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q24144143.txt) DO (
 SET "string=%%a"
 SET "string=!string:%oldversion%=%newversion%!"
 ECHO(!string!
)
)>newfile.txt

FC q24144143.txt newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

Although - since you say the file is in `%%f` then either assign `%%f` to a variable or call this routine passing `"%%f"` as a parameter and read file `"%~1"`

Comment: If you don't know old version how to extract the version from a string correctly?